# Cannot find Where expression with ExpressionVisitor after SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq, linq-expressions

I have a `ExpressionVisitor` derived class with following overridden `VisitMethodCall()` method.

```
class CommonExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable))
        {
            switch (node.Method.Name)
            {
                case nameof(Queryable.Where):
                    Visit(node.Arguments[0]);
                    return node;

                case nameof(Queryable.Select):
                    Visit(node.Arguments[0]);
                    return node;

                case nameof(Queryable.SelectMany):
                    Visit(node.Arguments[0]);
                    Visit(node.Arguments[1]);
                    Visit(node.Arguments[2]);
                    return node;
            }
        }
        return base.VisitMethodCall(node);
    }
}
```

The visitor can easily find `Where` expression when there is no `SelectMany` call in the query. Such as:

```
var queryable = from item in collection
                where item.X >= 0 && item.Y >= 0
                select item;
```

However, if the query contains `SelectMany`, the entire `Where` expression is gone and the visitor is unable to reach it anymore.

```
var queryable = from item in collection
                from sub in item.SubItems
                where sub.A >= 0 && sub.B >= 0
                select sub;
```

How do I fix my `ExpressionVisitor` in order to find `Where` expression?

Comment: Probably just best off putting a breakpoint at the start of your function and seeing what calls it gets. The only odd thing I can think of going on with the `SelectMany` call is that the LINQ conversion makes up a new variable to hold `item` and `sub` together, but I can't think why that would cause an issue.

Comment: It works for me. If I debug your code, I reach the case for the `Where` call. Maybe you are confused by the order or the expression nodes. Note that linq uses extensions, so the first argument is the `IQueryable` you are calling the method on, not the expression you see as first argument in code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going to answer my own question. There are two phases in the expression. In first phase the `IQueryable.Provider` property is called to generate anonymous objects that consists of two variables `item` and `sub`. In second phase, same property is called again where the expression now contains the anonymous type and `where` clause. So the `where` clause does not disappear, it is just in second phase.